# How do you programmatically pass in keywords to function in python?

Tags: python, refactoring, keyword

I have some code I'm trying to refactor, which looks a bit like this in python 3:

```
  # some_obj.query(streetaddress="burdon")
  # some_obj.query(area="bungo")
  # some_obj.query(region="bingo")
  # some_obj.query(some_other_key="bango")
```

How I can DRY this up so I have something like this?

```
# define a list of tuples like so:
set_o_tuples = [
  ("streetaddress", "burdon")
  ("area", "bungo"),
  ("region", "bingo"),
  ("some_other_key", "bango"),
])
```

And then call it in a function

```
for key, val in set_o_tuples:      
  some_obj.query(key=val)
```

When I try to run this code, I get an exception like the following - as Python doesn't like keywords being passed in like this:

```
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

What *is* the idiomatic way to DRY this up, so I don't have to repeat loads of code like the example above?

Update: sorry folks, I think the example I put together above missed a few important details. I basically have some pytest code like so

```
def test_can_search_by_location(self, db, docs_from_csv):
    """
    We want to be able to query the contents of all the below fields when we query by location:
    [ streetaddress, locality, region, postcode]
    """

    search = SomeDocument.search()

    locality_query = search.query('match', locality="some val")
    locality_res = locality_query.execute()

    region_query = search.query('match', region="region val")
    region_query_res = region_query.execute()

    postcode_query = search.query('match', postcode="postcode_val")
    postcode_query_res = postcode_query.execute()

    streetaddress_query = search.query('match', concat_field="burdon")
    field_query_res = field_query.execute()

    location_query = search.query('match', location=concat_value)
    location_query_res = location_query.execute()

    assert len(locality_query_res) == len(location_query_res)
    assert len(region_query_res) == len(location_query_res)
    assert len(streetaddress_query_res) == len(location_query_res)
    assert len(postcode_query_res) == len(location_query_res)
```

I was trying to DRY up some of this, as there are similar examples I have, but after reading the comments, I've rethought it - the savings in space don't really justify the changes. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: You should consult the official Python tutorial, it tells you how to provide keywords to functions. It's via dictionaries, not 2-ples.

Comment: In this case here, this is some test code, where I want to test them serially. I don't want to test them all in one go

Comment: That's not a different case, you're just using dictionaries with a single item each time.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a list of dictionaries instead, and then unpack them when calling the method in a loop:

```
list_of_dicts = [
    {"streetaddress": "burdon"}
    {"area": "bungo"},
    {"region": "bingo"},
    {"some_other_key": "bango"},
]

for kwargs in list_of_dicts:      
    some_obj.query(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [dictionary unpacking](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/dict_unpack.html)

```
some_obj.query(**{key: val})
```

---

I wouldn't recommend what you're doing though. The original method is clean and obvious. Your new one could be confusing. I would keep it as is. This looks to be a poorly designed python API, `some_obj.query` should just take multiple keyword arguments in one function. You could make your own like this:

```
def query(obj, **kwargs):
    # python 3.6 or later to preserve kwargs order
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        obj.query(**{key: value})
```

And then call like so

```
 query(some_obj, streetaddress='burdon', area='bungo', region='bingo', some_other_key='bango')
```